# Как вывести одновременно все посты и конкретный? Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Мой Controller:

```
public function post($code, $id){

      $specpost = Post::where('id', $id)->get();

      return view('post', compact('specpost'));
    }
```

Это способ, с помощью которого я получаю конкретный пост, выбранный пользователем. Но так же я хочу предлагать рандомно пользователю почитать какой либо другой пост. Как грамотно можно вывести другие посты? Просто взять и второй выборкой написать `$rand = Post::where('id', '<>', $id)->inRandomOrder()->limit(10)->get();` почему то мне кажется не совсем корректным. К тому же слышал, что если писать 2 выборки из одного контроллера, то он будет перегружен. Если другой способ это сделать? Например как-нибудь через eloquent связи и т.д.?

Спасибо!

Comment: Хочу поехать на велосипеде за молоком и хлебом. Но бабки у подъезда сказали что в два магазина по очереди ездят только лохи. Как можно поехать в два магазина разом? Например как-то надстроить велосипед чтобы он ехал в два места одновременно?

Comment: Просто из одно БД выборки происходят, думал мало ли можно как то иначе)

Comment: все можно. можно и гланды вырезать газовым резаком. но надо сначала спросить себя - зачем. что тебе даст усложнение простого, как две копейки, кода

Comment: Производительно тоже важна, поэтому стараюсь учиться сразу правильно) Понял, спасибо!)

Comment: КАКАЯ ЕЩЁ ПРОИЗВОДИТЕЛЬНОСТЬ? Кому важна? Какая производительность? Какую проблему ты хочешь решить? С чего ты взял что твое решение решит какие-то проблемы, а не создаст их? Откуда вообще возник вопрос про производительность?

Comment: Слишком частое обращение к БД это производительно? В этом я пытаюсь разобраться. Одно дело когда на локалке, не заметно, на хостинге по другому ведь будет.

Comment: Что такое "слишком частое"? Что такое "обращение к БД"? Какую конкретно проблему ты хочешь решить? какую проблему создают тебе эти два запроса? Мыться каждый день - это непроизводительно, вода расходуется. Поэтому мыться надо раз в месяц, да?  Пачкать две тарелки в обед - это непроизводительно. Клади сразу в одну и суп и второе. И компот сверху налей. Это будет производительно. Экономия чистой посуды же! Ведь все наши действия должны быть подчинены только одной цели - улучшению производительности!

Answer (score 1):

```
public function post($code, $id){

        $specpost = Post::find($id);

        // получаем кол-во всех постов
        $postsCount = Post::count();

        // определяем массив рандомных чисел
        $suggestPostsIds = [];

        // циклом добавляем рандомное число в массив. Будет выполнено 150 попыток подобрать уникальный ID.
        for ($i = 0; $i < 150; $i++) {
            $num = rand(1, $postsCount); // от 1 до последнего поста

            // прерываем цикл, если в массиве уже достаточное кол-во ID
            if (count($suggestPostsIds) === 4) break;

            // проверяем, не повторяется ли число? если нет, добавляем в массив
            if (!in_array($num, $suggestPostsIds)) {
                array_push($suggestPostsIds, $num);
            }
        }

        // получаем посты по рандомным ID
        $suggestPosts = Post::whereIn('id', $suggestPostsIds)->get();
        
        // осталось передать во вью

        return view('post', compact('specpost'));
    }
```

Обращений к базе данных должно быть столько, сколько нужно данных для работы приложения, на то она и база данных. 30-50-100 запросов к БД это норма.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Но есть ли смысл писать на чистом php функцию рандомной выборки, если у Laravel предусмотрена несколько(если не ошибаюсь) функций "из коробки", например inRandomOrder()?
Да и смысл поста был, спросить насколько правильно из одного котроллера писать 2 запроса в БД, к тому же в одну таблицу. Но целом понял, что это нормально.

Comment: Да, действительно, можно использовать любые методы коллекций, предоставляющиеся Laravel.